# Unable to connect to master or target server "ServerName"

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sql-server, unit-testing

Have some troubles with Unit Test and Dackpack. This is the full error name:

> DeploymentFailedException: Unable to connect to master or target server 'DBTests'. You must have a user with the same password in the master or target server 'DBTests'.

I have 3 strange things :

1. I can publish my Database on Server (tests have the same connection string)
2. I can log in in my site and I don't have troubles with DB (using IIS)
3. Test logic: Test database created when I init my tests, and it is really created!!!!

But all tests have "Error".

I upgrade my SSDT. I reinstall MSSQL Twice. And I set `compability level(130)`. And what is so funny this is my Connection Strings when I try to debug my tests:

```
"Data Source=ServerName;integrated security=false;Initial Catalog=DbTests;User ID=kek;Password=kek;Connection Timeout=60;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Max Pool Size=1024"
```

That is TestDatabase connection string. And she is absolutely fine because I TESTED this connection string.

This is masterDatabase connection string:

```
Data Source=ServerName;integrated security=false;Initial Catalog=master;User ID=kek;Password=kek;Connection Timeout=60;MultipleActiveResultSets=True
```

And the main question what I have: Why Error say what 'DBTest' - this is a server ?? I mean, this is DB, not server.

Maybe someone knows about that, idk. That is so stupid and I can't understand what's wrong.

UPD: I solve my problem. Installed SQL Server 2016.

P.S. Ofc I can log in on the server with my "kek", "kek" credentials in Management Studio.

Comment: can you share `publish.xm`l content in SSDT project

Comment: i solved my problem , thank you

Comment: welcome, what was the issue?

Comment: @ElasticCode well, my binaries files created for SQL 2016. And all my DackPack settings write for SQL Server 2016. My second day on my new work... and I'm junior, so sad...

Comment: I am also facing the same issue while deploying dacpac from VS 2019 to database 2019 via Azure CD pipeline, error is:                                                         Unable to connect to master or target server 'ActionDB'. You must have a user with the same password in master or target server 'ActionDB'.